# Why I have an error in .txt file in Eclipse when start with {

Tags: eclipse

[image]

I have this error in Eclipse, when I tried to add a new txt file with { at beginning. How can I turn off this error?

Comment: What editor are you using for the file? Right click on the file in Project/Package Explorer and look at which editor is selected in the 'Open With' menu.

Comment: it is using Text Editor

Comment: Are you saying it is only lines starting with '{'? The plain text editor doesn't care about the contents, the only thing it does is spell checking.